# Unable to get instagram_story_id from the adcreative

Tags: python, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am building a program to get instagram ad comments using Facebook Marketing API. I am using [facebook-python-ads-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-ads-sdk). I am able to get the accounts and the ads. But I need the instagram_story_id to get the comments as mentioned here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/instagramads/ad_creative/v2.8#posts.
This is the code I am using to test the API.

```
from facebookads.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebookads import objects
from facebookads.adobjects.adset import AdSet


insta_fields=[  
                objects.AdCreative.Field.instagram_actor_id,
                objects.AdCreative.Field.instagram_story_id,
                objects.AdCreative.Field.instagram_permalink_url,

]

app_id = "<app-id>"
app_secret = "<app-secret>"
access_token = "<accesss-token>"

FacebookAdsApi.init(app_id, app_secret, access_token)
account = objects.AdAccount("<account-id>")

for aset in account.get_ad_sets():
    adset = AdSet(aset['id'])
    for c in adset.get_ad_creatives():
        c.api_get(fields=insta_fields) 
        print(c)
```

I am able to get the actor_id and permalink_url but not the story_id, is there any other way to get it or am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should use effective_instagram_story_id instead.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I used.